# Command after close Nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I open Nautilus by command line in new window. I want to execute another command after nautilus is closed. Like this :

```
bash -c 'sshfs -o idmap=user my_user@192.168.1.200:/ /media/192.168.1.200 | nautilus /media/192.168.1.200;fusermount -u /media/192.168.1.200'
```

In this case, I want to execute `fusermount -u /media/192.168.1.200` only after Nautilus is closed.

Is possible ?

Addendum: I often multiple Nautilus windows open. So I want to close this window ONLY.

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do it. I guess the only way to achieve this is to use some script to note the id of the new window, poll if it still exists, and call the next command when the window is destroyed. May be nautilus scripts offer a better way, but not sure.

Comment: Nautilus scripts/actions is certainly not a solution. And and I don't know how to find the id of the new window (this specific window). I guess I'll have to fusermount the filesystem manually...

Comment: Actually I solved an manual solution . I created a .desktop file who changes his icon  depending on the state of fileystem (mounted or unmounted). This is to see that connection has remained mounted for no reason and unmount it with double-click (and icon change to unmounted). If no one will find another solution will stay with it.

Comment: @Mahesh, I use nautilus-actions after connection is open (filesystem mounted) for edit-delete-create files/folders with root privileges (sudo) over ssh and with scripts located on server and local using expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a concrete answer, but few pointers that may help.

If the window has a unique title, you can get its window id using

```
NAUTILUS_WINDOWID=`xwininfo -name <title> |grep 'Window id' |awk '{print $4}'`
```

Now periodically calling `xwininfo -id $NAUTILUS_WINDOWID >/dev/null` should do the trick.

It returns `0` if the window exists, and `1` otherwise.

Comment: 10x @Mahesh, but i don't know why Nautilus has no names to windows. (I use Gnome minimal desktop over Ubuntu server 12.04)

Comment: The title is usually the foldername. Assuming you have no other windows that have the foldername as title, you should hit the right window with the given command. and re: your comment, what exactly do you mean by 'names to windows' ?

Comment: try `xwininfo |grep 'Window id'`  When it asks you to click a window, click on the nautilus window. That will tell you what its title is (The part in quotes). But anyway, titles not appearing is a weird thing IMO.

Comment: Thank you again. That may be a solution that will study tomorrow. The only problem is how often they check the window state ... I do not know what to say. A _while_ loop with 1 second pause perhaps ...  I don't know now.

Comment: By the way, if you change the root directory (eg. /media/192.168.1.200/home) then _xwininfo -name 192.168.1.200 |grep 'Window id |awk '{print $4}'_ return *No window with name "192.168.1.200" exists!*  With _xwininfo -name 192.168.1.200 |grep 'Window id' |awk '{print $4}'_  all is ok.

Comment: Use window name only for the first time. Once you get the id, use it instead. It wont change for whole session. `xwininfo -id <id>` insteadof `xwininfo -name <title>`

Comment: Right. I will do some tests tomorrow. Thanks again for your interest. (+1 for now)

Answer (score 2):

This work :

```
#!/bin/bash
sshfs -o idmap=user my_user@192.168.1.200:/ /media/192.168.1.200 | nautilus /media/192.168.1.200
sleep 1
lc_id=`xwininfo -name 192.168.1.200 |grep 'Window id' |awk '{print $4}'`

while [ ! -z "$(xwininfo -id "$lc_id" | grep "Absolute upper-left X" )" ]
do
   sleep 1
done
fusermount -u /media/192.168.1.200
```

Credits go to @Mahesh

Comment: Glad it helped. :) you can drop that `grep "Absolute..."` part. Just `$(xwininfo -id "$lc_id")` should work there.

Comment: You're right. The string is empty anyway.